# How to find a pattern from list1 and then to replace the previous line from list2

Tags: linux, redhat

I have one file and 2 lists

```
[RECORD]
Name: test1
Loc: x
Mob: y
[RECORD]
Name: test2
Loc: xx
Mob: yy
```

and List_old:

```
x
xx
```

List_new

```
0001
1110
```

And need to search, if found Loc: x (x from list_old), then replace Mob: y into Mob: 0001 (0001 from new_list)

The ouput shoul be:

```
[RECORD]
Name: test1
Loc: x
Mob: 0001
[RECORD]
Name: test2
Loc: xx
Mob: 1110
```

Answer (score 0):

Are all old entries of the type `Mob: y`? If so, then you do not really need to correspond your replacement to `Loc: x` as the Mob record is already unique.

If this is sufficient, you can use:

```
perl -p -i-bkup -e 's/Mob: y/Mob: 0001/g' FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick-and-dirty script you can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

die "Use: replace.pl <file> <list1> <list2>" unless $#ARGV==2;

open LIST1, $ARGV[1] or die $ARGV[1].": $!";
open LIST2, $ARGV[2] or die $ARGV[2].": $!";
open FILE,  $ARGV[0] or die $ARGV[0].": $!";

while (<LIST1>) {
  chomp;
  $key=$_;
  $value=<LIST2>;
  chomp $value;
  $hash->{$key}=$value;
}

while (<FILE>) {
  if (/^Loc: (.*)/) {
    $repl=$hash->{$1};
  }
  if (/^Mob: (.*)/ and defined $repl) {
    s/Mob: (.*)/Mob: $repl/;
    $repl=undef;
  }

  print;
}

close LIST1;
close FILE;
close LIST1;
```

A hope I understood well what you try to achieve. This script prints the result to stdout, and does not change the lines which has no corresponding pattern in the lists. Also, it assumes the lists have the same size, and overall, does very little to avoid errors.